# How to change application name in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I Have just installed `Laravel 5.8` and I want to change the application name from `Laravel` to `CodeTube`.
I have written this in `.env` file `APP_NAME=CudeTube` but the Name didn't change.

Comment: In this file `config/app.php` , you have to change `'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),` into `'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'CodeTube'),`

Comment: Try `php artisan config:clear` and restart the artisan server and test.

Comment: stopping the server and restarting was enough to solve the issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following command to rename your application

```
php artisan app:name CodeTube
```

[Laravel Manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#after-installation)

Comment: not working in Laravel 8.x and result in: `There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace.`

Answer (score 1):

Try `php artisan config:clear` and restart the artisan server and test.

You need to clear config once you changed the setting and to see the changes, restart the artisan server if you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to .env file to rename your app

```
APP_NAME=CodeTube
```

use this command to clear the configuration cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the app folder and navigate to the .env file and change APP_NAME=APP_NAME=Hospital_Management_System --> ensure no whitespace
2. Navigate to the config folder and under app.php change the name same as above
   'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Hospital_Management_System'),
   Again do not leave a whitespace.
3. Stop the server
4. Start the server